# Given the following information, find $\textbf{P}(A\cap B)$.

Tags: probability, statistics

Given that $\textbf{P}(A) = 0.3, \textbf{P}(A\cup B) = 0.4$ as well as $A$ and $B$ are independent, what is the probability of $\textbf{P}(A\cap B)$?

Answer (score 1):

$P(A\cup B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A\cap B)=P(A)+P(B)-P(A)P(B)$. Plug in the value of $P(A)$ and solve for $P(B)$. Then use the fact that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Given that $A$ and $B$ are independent, you know that $P(A \cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$, and thus $P(B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$

Also, it is *always* true that $P(A \cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cup B)$

So, plug in what you have, and the equation for $P(B)$ from above, and solve for $P(A \cap B)$